# Typescript not addressing missing properties

Tags: typescript, types

I am using TypeScript in VSCode and I am wondering why I am not getting an error when I create an object of type `Thing` or adhering to interface `IThing`

***code.ts***

```
type Thing = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

const t1 = <Thing>{}; // No error for missing properties
const t2 = {} as Thing; // No error for missing properties
const t3 = <Thing>{ bad: 'wrong ' }; // intellisense returns ERROR below
const t4 = { bad: 'wrong ' } as Thing; // intellisense returns ERROR below

interface IThing {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const it1 = <IThing>{}; // No error for missing properties
const it2 = {} as IThing; // No error for missing properties
const it3 = <IThing>{ bad: 'wrong ' }; // intellisense returns IERROR below
const it4 = { bad: 'wrong ' } as IThing; // intellisense returns IERROR below


// ERROR: "Conversion of type '{ bad: string; }' to type 'Thing' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Type '{ bad: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Thing': id, name"
// IERROR: "Conversion of type '{ bad: string; }' to type 'IThing' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Type '{ bad: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IThing': id, name"
```

***.eslintrc.json***

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      2,
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ],
    "no-console": [
      1,
      {
        "allow": ["warn", "error"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "root": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is due to [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

Both `<Thing>{}` and `{} as Thing` are type assertions that tell the compiler to perform less strict type checking than usual.

As shown in the question, the compiler will still pick up on overlap issues, which can be further ignored by using the form `{} as unknown as Thing`.

**To ensure strong type checking**, use the following form:

```
const t: Thing = {}
```

Which results in this error:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Thing': id, name.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit, You have no overvap between `Thing` and `{ bad: string }`

You don't have any error with the empty object because there is an overlap : `{}`